# How do I add a field to an object using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a CRUD app using the MEAN stack and I have a Mongoose schema (Freezer) set up with an empty object:

```
shelves: {}
```

What I'm trying to do is push additional objects to this object, e.g.:

```
[shelfname] : {name : [shelfname]}
```

So over time the shelves object would resemble something like:

```
shelves : {

           shelf1: {name: shelf1},
           shelf2: {name: shelf2},
           shelf3: {name: shelf3},


}
```

I'm trying the following code and it's not working:

```
var shelf = req.body.shelf
  console.log(shelf);
  var shelfname = req.body.shelf.shelfname;


  var conditions = {_id : req.body._id};

  var update = {$set: {shelfname : shelfname}};

  Freezer.update(conditions, update, function(err,freezer){
    console.log(freezer);




  });
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an an array of subdocuments for shelves of a freezer:

```
var FreezerModel = new Schema({
    shelves: [String]
});
```

Then use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/) operator to add a shelf to your freezer:

```
var shelf = req.body.shelf,
    id = req.body._id;
Freezer.update({_id: id}, {$push: {shelves: shelf}}, function(err, freezer) {
    console.log(freezer);
});
```

If you want to stick with the objects rather than arrays, I suggest you use array notation for modifying fields:

```
var FreezerModel = new Schema({
    shelves: Schema.Types.Mixed
});

var update = {$set: {}};
update['$set']['shelves.'+shelfname] = shelfname;
```

This is because in js object notation a key is always interpreted as a literal, so if you want to use a variable for key, you need to use an array notation.
Using type `Mixed` for `shelves` is due to Mongoose in strict mode limits you to fields defined in the schema. You can also use {strict: false} for schema options. See [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1867) for details.

Comment: I tried that implementation and had it working but I'm trying to avoid having many arrays of nested arrays, and also I want to be able to access properties based on field names (rather than array indices)

Comment: @Leif - I have updated my answer for fields solution.